# Find A from $e^{At}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given a fundemanetal matrix $e^{At}$ and am asked to find $A$. It's kind of an odd question as we've mainly been calculating $e^{At}$ when given a certain matrix $A$. My question is how do I find $A$ and if you can always find $A$ for any fundamental matrix. Anyways this was given:

\begin{align}
e^{At}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
2e^{2t}-e^t & e^{2t}-e^t&e^t-e^{2t} \\
e^{2t}-e^t & 2e^{2t}-e^t&e^t-e^{2t} \\
3e^{2t}-3e^t & 3e^{2t}-3e^t&3e^t-2^{2t} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the derivative towards $t$ and plug in $t=0$.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! Thanks. I'm assuming since $e^{At}=X(t)X(0)^{-1}$ for a fundamental solution $X(t)$ we can always find $A$.

Comment: \begin{align}
A&=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1&-1 \\
1 & 3&-1 \\
3& 3&-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: can you please tell me? Am I calculating the correct matrix?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Correct. (You can also take a look in the answers of odd numbered exercises.)

Comment: which textbook?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Martin Braun: Differential Equations and their Applications